# Actionscript 3.0 type downcast issue

Tags: actionscript-3, downcast, type-coercion

I have implemented a new class that extends MovieClip. It's name is `base.MovieClipWithDelays` ("base" here is a package name).

My scene contains such an object named `Blah`.
In `Symbol Properties` I checked `Export for ActionScript` and `Export in first frame` checkboxes.
I set Class Name as `T_Idle_0`.
And I specified it's Base class as `base.MovieClipWithDelays`.

The problem is that following code leads to the Type Error:

```
var dob:DisplayObject = getChild("Blah");
trace("SuperClass = " + getQualifiedSuperclassName(dob));
return MovieClipWithDelays(dob);
```

it outputs:

```
SuperClass = base::MovieClipWithDelays
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert T_Idle_0@1ec59e9 to base.MovieClipWithDelays.
```

As you can see, it's superclass name is OK. Nevertheless, it fails to downcast it. How is it possible and how do I workaround it?

Comment: Update: if I add debugging line trace("Is = " + (dob is base.MovieClipWithDelays)); it says "Is = false"....

Comment: are you using a single SWF, or using multiple SWFs?

Comment: What does `getQualifiedClassName` return?

Comment: > are you using a single SWF, or using multiple SWFs? 
I use multiple SWFs. When I use single SWF, it works great. But when scene mentioned is loaded from another SWF, it fails to downcast.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot set the base class of a library MovieClip to a custom class. You can either set it to Sprite or MovieClip. To do what you want to do, you have two solutions:

1 . Manage everything (drawing, etc.) from your MovieClipWithDelays class. i.e. don't make it depend on a library object.

Or:

2 . Make your MovieClipWithDelays wraps a MovieClip instance.

```
var libraryMC:MovieClip = new SomeLibraryMovieClip();
var customMc:MovieClipWithDelays = new MovieClipWithDelays(libraryMC);
```

Then within `MovieClipWithDelays`, you'll need to have some function and properties to handle the wrapped MovieClip.

Comment: Afraid this answer is false; you can set a custom class as base class (I have done this successfully many times). The custom class should still inherit from Sprite or MovieClip.

Comment: I never got that working, so I've always assumed it had to be a built-in ActionScript class.

Comment: I'm not so experienced, but as I read from Colin Moock's book "Essential ActionScript 3.0", it is OK to have a custom base class.

I think the problem has different origin. When I use single SWF, it works great. But when scene (that contains that "Blah" object) is loaded from another SWF, it fails to downcast.